# If I use a joomla hosting provider, am I able to customize the PHP *completely*?

Tags: web-hosting, joomla

not sure if this is the right place to ask.

Joomla is offered by many hosting providers.  I have set up joomla 1.7 on my local machine, and I've found a nice template to start with. But I customized it for my needs -resizing divs, modifying the css extensively, and even modifying index.php in some cases.

will I be able to do the same if I host a joomla installation at a hosting provider?

How do I get the modified PHP up to the hoster? Is it FTP only or is there some other remote access offered?

Answer (score 5):

It's highly dependent on your hosting provider. I they allow you to use FTP you just upload your theme and select it under Joomla control panel.

Answer (score 1):

It obviously depends on the hoster. I assume that nearly all web hosting companies allow uploading files through ftp, which *should* allow you to even switch from joomla to something else. You will have to see what the hosting company offers and you might even have to send an email to make sure if they don't advertise it and you can't see what you're allowed to do before signing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are right, you should definitively do a trial with the desired hoster.

However, at least with **Version 3** of Joomla, you could also manipulate the php from inside joomla, which makes it extremely likely that also preinstallations would allow this. This at least is the case with my own hoster.